# ESP32-WROVER-E low-power custom board validation

Tags: pcb, schematics, low-power, esp32

I recently finished my degree in Electronics Engineering. My experience with that degree is that you learn a lot of things, but you don't go really deep into any subject.

So I'm trying to solve that by going deep into the world of microcontrolers, specifically with the ESP32 microcontroler.

I've bought a lot of ESP32 development boards, I did some IoT projects, low-power projects, and Wi-Fi and BLE management, and now I would like to make a custom board for two purposes:

1. To have the capability to create a system for a specific purpose.
2. To better understand this microcontroler and all its functions.

According to these purposes I made a custom board; you can check the schematic in the next screenshot:

[image]

The system has the following specifications:

- Low-power board (35 μA aprox quiescent current on Deep Sleep, according to the voltage regulator)
- Battery-powered (input between 1.5 V - 6.5 V)
- JTAG Debugging
- No micro USB (programm is uploaded and monitored directly from UART0)

I'm writing this post because, as I said above, we didn't go deep into these kinds of subjects, and I would like to validate this board before sending it to produce a prototype and test it.

In the schematic you have all the components' names and each part is separated for better understanding.

I just would like to see if I have made any fatal errors that could make the board fail. I reviewed the schematic a few times and I didn't find any fatal errors. I know there are a lot of professionals in this forum, maybe someone who did more custom ESP32 boards could check it?

Thank you very much for your time.

Toni.

Comment: Your schematic is full of doglegs. Spend some time on the schematic and get it looking sensible. C3 says 10uF - are you sure you’re getting the full 10uF? Have you taken into account possible loss of capacitance due to voltage bias? What is the recommended component by Espressif?

Comment: @Kartman Thank you very much for your response sir! I never heard the word "doglegs" (i'm not english native) but i understand u are refering to the abrupt changes in the wires, instead of being straight? In reference to the capacitors question, i used to follow this hardware guidelines from ESP32, that's the reason for that values of capacitors. https://www.espressif.com/sites/default/files/documentation/esp32_hardware_design_guidelines_en.pdf

Comment: @Kartman 10uF is on the low end for the ESP32. Espressif themselves moved from 10 to 22uF on later eval boards. 10uF will probably work if you're careful (X7R dielectric and sufficient voltage rating).

Comment: @TypeIA, this was what I was outlining. i’ve always used 22uF. TSBox seems to be unaware of the voltage bias spec of ceramic capacitors which is likely to catch them unawares.

Comment: You probably don't want 100R series termination on RST and IO0(DL#). It would likely still work, but you want to be able to pull those all the way to GND. These are pure DC signals so there is no sense in termination. (Also just noticed you have 100R series "termination" for the GND pin, you definitely don't want that!)

Comment: You can also improve your JTAG termination. See [this page](https://www.xjtag.com/about-jtag/design-for-test-guidelines/) for recommended termination and pullups. But BE CAREFUL not to disrupt the strapping pins. In particular don't pull MTDI up if you have 3.3V flash!

Comment: Thank you very much to you guys for your time , I'll definitively research on this subjects and improve the board :)